# How can I solve EJBCLIENT000079 Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException?

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I want to make a EJB project USE Intellij IDEA.But there was a wrong on it.My project has tow model in a project,One is server and the other is client.I want to start server and run client to execute a sayHello function,but get failed.

My SessionBean Interface And Client Interface

```
package com.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloWorld {
    public String sayHello(String world);
}
```

My SessionBean Class

```
import com.ejb.HelloWorld;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(name = "HelloWorldEJB")
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld {
    public HelloWorldBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String world) {
        return "hello"+world;
    }
}
```

My client Class

```
package com.ejb;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class HelloWorldClient {
    private static HelloWorld lookupRemoteStatelessEjbBean() throws NamingException {
        final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        String namespace="ejb:/EJBServer_war_exploded/HelloWorldEJB!com.ejb.HelloWorld";
        return (HelloWorld) context.lookup(namespace);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = lookupRemoteStatelessEjbBean();
        System.out.println(helloWorld);
        String s = helloWorld.sayHello("world");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

My properties(this properties has put in src folder exactly)

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connection.default.username=admin
remote.connection.default.password=123456
```

First I start server and intellij IDEA automatically put war folder into JBOSS(WildFly) 11.I visited EJB amdin website,and war folder exactly in server.
The error code is

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination for request for EJB StatelessEJBLocator for "/EJBServer_war_exploded/HelloWorldEJB", view is interface com.ejb.HelloWorld, affinity is None
```

I don't know how to solve it,and I had searched on bing and google.No one had the same question,how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5):

**For WildFly11 use the following configuration:**

jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");

**instead of:**

jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

Comment: it is not solution

Answer (score 2):

as far as i'm concerned, replace String

```
namespace="ejb:/EJBServer_war_exploded/HelloWorldEJB!com.ejb.HelloWorld";
```

with
String

```
namespace="ejb:/EJBServer_war_exploded/HelloWorldBean!com.ejb.HelloWorld";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked for me.